# How to get asset content in Play Framework

Tags: playframework

I'm working on Play Framework version 1, I need to get the asset content (JS or CSS file) under public folder for merging. For instance, I want to merge 2 JS files into 1 file and process something on it.

Anyone know how to do that with Play 1, or how to merge some assets for rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I decide use VirtualFile provided by Play for asset manipulation, read and merge them  when needed.

Thanks for your help, @green

Answer (score 0):

There are playframework v1 modules dealing with js/css asset merge/compress. You can try either [greenscript](http://www.playframework.com/modules/greenscript) or [press](http://www.playframework.com/modules/press)

Comment: disclaimer: I am the author of greenscript. BTW since play doesn't provide v1 module update, you need to go to http://gelinsoft.com/play/repo/ to get the latest version of greenscript

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. However, I want to have a new method in Java code to load an asset content and process it before rendering

Comment: hmm... greenscript doesn't provide hooks to inject your own logic to process the asset for the moment. I am not sure if press has the feature. Probably you need to write your own module or fork greenscript to add your logic